# How can I tell if a given Linq-to-Sql object is attached to a datacontext?

Tags: linq-to-sql, datacontext

I use linq 2 sql for my ORM.

For performance reasons, I serialize some of them, and throw them into memcached.

When they're deserialized, they're of course not attached to a datacontext, which is 100% fine, as they're only used for reading from in those scenarios.

For sanity reasons however, I'd like to be able to tell whether a given object is attached to a datacontext (fetched from the db), or not (fetched from memcached).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use GetOriginalEntityState. Here's a test.

```
Customer cust = new Customer();
ctx.Customers.Attach(cust);

Customer orig = ctx.Customers.GetOriginalEntityState(cust);

//test if orig is null
```

Comment: Thanks David, that does seem to work. 

However, when you try to attach an entity that did come from the context, it throws an exception, which could get expensive if this check was run frequently as a guard :\

Comment: Just using the `GetOriginalEntityState` method and a null check without the calling `Attach` first seems to work e.g. `entityTable.InsertAllOnSubmit( entities.Where( e => entityTable.GetOriginalEntityState( e ) == null ) )` correctly inserts all the new entities.